# SkillSoft Web Service Issues

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Using Visual Studio 2005 and C# .NET I was attempting to call methods from the SkillSoft API through their web service and have been running into issues when creating the instance. I started by adding the web service reference to the project (Add Web Reference) and that works fine. Where I get tripped up is in the main .cs where I wish to call the methods I create an instance with the line of code:

SkillSoftWebService.OlsaService service = new SkillSoftWebService.OlsaService();

When I build and run this I get a CS0029 error: InvalidOperationException and it mentioned implicitly converting the queryInclude type to the queryExclude type. I know this question is specific to only those using Skillsoft but I was wondering if anyone had found a work around to this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the complete error message you get. And clarify if you get this message on a build, or when you run. Make sure you know what line number the message refers to.

Comment: John,
The full error message, which occurs on run, is the following:

Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Example.SkillSoftWebService.queryInclude' to 'Example.SkillSoftWebService.queryExclude'

Comment: Figured this out, it was an error in their code so I just commented out the offending line and the Web Service functioned properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in my last comment, it was actually an issue with the Web Service provided methods so I was able to work around this generic exception by just removing the offending method (since I didn't need it).